# Only update RecyclerView when a change in the dataset occurs

Tags: android

I have a dataset of restaurants and a recycler view where they are displayed. Depending on a few options, they should or not be visible: opening time, food type, etc.

Right now every time the activity with the recycler view is opened I run `adapter.updateDataset()` which internally goes through the whole dataset, creates a subset based on all the possible filters, and then does `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

How can I make it so that I only need to run `adapter.updateDataset()` when a change actually occurs? Since these changes occur in a different context from the RecyclerView activity, I can't just call the function there. What alternative do I have, to improve performance?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a list of [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) objects either from room or a network resource and bind it your viewmodel. Then you will be observing the changes in your fragment/activity. When the change occurs, update the adapters data list and do not forget to use [DiffUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil?hl=en) in order to update only changed items. A good example is in google [sample codes](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/BasicSample) on room database usage.

In your Room Dao query it should be like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM products")
LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> loadProducts();
```

Then in your viewmodel:

```
public class ProductListViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    // MediatorLiveData can observe other LiveData objects and react on their emissions.
    private final MediatorLiveData<List<ProductEntity>> observableProducts;

    public ProductListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        observableProducts = new MediatorLiveData<>();
        // set by default null, until we get data from the database.
        observableProducts.setValue(null);

        LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> products = ((YourBaseApp) application).getRepository()
                .loadProducts();
        observableProducts.addSource(products, observableProducts::setValue);
    }

    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory {

        @NonNull
        private final Application mApplication;

        public Factory(@NonNull Application application) {
            mApplication = application;
        }

        @Override
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create(Class<T> modelClass) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new ProductListViewModel(mApplication);
        }
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProductList() {
        return observableProducts;
    }

}
```

Then in your activity/fragment onCreate you may call such a sample function and start observing your data:

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Binding is of type ProductListLayoutBinding
        // you need to declare it on tope of your fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.product_list_layout, container, false); 

        // your other stuff if needed..

        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(/*...Your parameters if any*/);
        binding.yourRecylerViewId.setAdapter(productAdapter);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //...
        //...
        // do your normal stuff above
        ProductListViewModel.Factory factory = new ProductListViewModel.Factory(
                YourBaseApp.getInstance());
        final ProductListViewModel viewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ProductListViewModel.class);
        subscribeUi(viewModel);

    }

    private void subscribeUi(ProductListViewModel viewModel) {
            // Update the list when the data changes
            viewModel.getProductList().observe(this, new Observer<List<ProductEntity>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ProductEntity> myProducts) {
                    if (myProducts != null) {
                        if (myProducts.size() == 0) {
                            binding.setIsLoading(true);
                        } else {
                            binding.setIsLoading(false);
                            productAdapter.setProductList(myProducts);
                        }
                    } else {
                        binding.setIsLoading(true);
                    }
                    binding.executePendingBindings();
                }

            });
        }
```

Finally on your adapter:

```
public void setProductList(final List<? extends Product> inProductList) {
        if (productList == null) {
            productList = inproductList;
            notifyItemRangeInserted(0, productList.size());
        } else {
            DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {
                @Override
                public int getOldListSize() {
                    return productList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public int getNewListSize() {
                    return inproductList.size();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                    return productList.get(oldItemPosition).getId() == inproductList.get(newItemPosition).getId();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                    productList newProduct = inproductList.get(newItemPosition);
                    productList oldProduct = productList.get(oldItemPosition);
                    return newProduct.getId() == oldProduct.getId()
                            && Objects.equals(newProduct.getDefinition(), oldProduct.getDefinition())
                            //... compare other properties
                            //...
                            ;
                }
            });
            productList = inproductList;
            result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
        }

    }
```

Hope , this helps.

Comment: I don't fully understand. I think I need to observe changes in the objects which might influence the filters. For example, I need to observe the selected food types. After being notified that a food type was changed, I then update the list which I pass onto the RecyclerView. Is this correct? So why do I need a list of LiveData objects then? Also, does this mean that the rest of the app should be updating LiveData objects instead of the objects themselves? In a way that my models are encapsulated by LiveData objects instead.

Comment: "After being notified that a food type was changed, I then update the list which I pass onto the RecyclerView. Is this correct?" Yes. "So why do I need a list of LiveData objects then?" This is because LiveData checks for the update not you, therefore if the onChange method is called you can be sure that data is updated if not the vice-versa. You just need to encapsulate your querry return value with LiveData that is all. Not much of a work you will see and it is safe considering the life-cycle of the fragment/activity.

Comment: and with implementing DiffUtil, your adapter only repaints the changed items, not whole list. Therefore you won't see flickering for all of your adapter items.

Comment: LiveData only notifies you for the change. You need to update the adapter list your self.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting the point, I'll read a few examples about it.

Comment: Edited my answer to help you out, hope it helps.

Comment: I really appreciate you took your time to do that, but I'm still a beginner and I don't understand Android well enough to comprehend all that's going on. I will refer back to this in the future after learning more about it. Thank you